# Many people write `javascript:void(0)` instead of `javascript:void 0` in hrefs. Do the parentheses do anything?

Tags: javascript

I see people write `void(0)` all the time, but I don't understand why people use parentheses. As far as I can tell, they have no purpose. `void` is not a function, it's an operator. So why do people use the parens? Do they serve a purpose? [Even on MDN the parens are used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

Comment: +1, interesting. Indeed, why not `void 42`?

Comment: Even [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) you provided says `void 0` and `void(0)` are equivalent.

Comment: unary text operators look weird to a lot of programmers.  If it's part of a larger expression though, then the parens control precedence, ya?  e.g. void (1+2)

Comment: @Cameron that would be an extra byte.

Comment: Well then, why not `void 1` or `void 7`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to admit that I've used that same construct many times in the past, mainly because I've seen it being used on other sites. I'm no longer using this because unobtrusive JavaScript is preferred over inline JavaScript; in fact, it's almost exclusively used inline to make sure the page doesn't refresh.

Having said that, as you have rightfully pointed out, it's an operator and not a function; the reason it still works is simply because `(0)` and `0` are the same thing, so this is how it would be evaluated:

```
void (0);
```

Which is identical to:

```
void 0;
```

I guess the reason it's being written as a function invocation is because people feel more comfortable with functions when used inline :)

```
<a href="javascript:void 0">...</a> // hold on, that can't work, can it?!

<a href="javascript:void(0)">...</a> // ahhh, normality restored
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"So why do people use the parens?"*

People do silly things.

> *"Do they serve a purpose?"*

No, they're not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.coderenaissance.com/2011/02/javascripts-void-operator-explained.html) explains it for you.

> One thing this clarifies is that void is an operator (not a function).Because of this void(0) is technically incorrect though in practice
>   implementations allow it to be used this way it should be used without
>   parentheses e.g. void 0.

So its technically wrong to use `void(0)` but in practise void has two different syntaxes:

```
void (expression)
void expression
```

**MDN** already tells you that, though no explicit statement has been made regarding the two syntaxes, as its not technically correct.

**Courtesy:**

- http://www.coderenaissance.com/2011/02/javascripts-void-operator-explained.html
- http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/void.php
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: The `()` isn't part of the `void` operator syntax, any more than a `+` would be in this expression: `void +0`. http://es5.github.com/#x11.4

Comment: Well... that article is technically incorrect to say: *"`void(0)` is technically incorrect but implementations allow it"*. It would  be incorrect for implementations to *not* allow it, because `0` is an expression, and expressions can be grouped in `()`. I just meant that the `()` isn't part of the `void` syntax, as shown by the grammar in the spec.

Comment: @user1689607, In that case it was technically incorrect to say that `()` isn't part of the syntax, as the specification specifies that void accepts `unary expression` as paramter and expressions, as we know can be grouped in parantheses.

Comment: @saji89: It can be part of the syntax of whatever unary expression is provided, but it isn't part of the `void` syntax, like you would have with the `for` syntax, which *requires* the `()`. http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.3 Notice the `(` and `)` are noted as part of the grammar.