# Why is the 0 in void(0) often enclosed in parenthesis?

Tags: javascript

Why is the JavaScript "do-nothing" snippet `void(0)` often written as such? Why not just `void 0`? Is there any particular reason why the `0` is so often enclosed in (unnecessary) parenthesis?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) that `void(0)` is equivalent to `void 0`, as `void` is an operator.

Could this possibly be the same type of confusion as enclosing the `typeof` operand in parenthesis? (Like `typeof(value) === 'string'`?) Is it the same case where many people seem to believe `void` is a function?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291950/1468130) states that

> `void(0)` is just the smallest script possible that evaluates as `undefined`.

But `void 0` is actually one character shorter, and seems to behave equivalently, at least in Chrome 43.

Comment: A style choice? I don't see this as being answerable. You already stated that the two are functionally equivalent. Speaking personally, I couldn't give a rat's arse about `void 0` being "one character shorter"; `void(0)` looks nicer. Anyway, who needs to use `void(0)` any more? It's 2015. :-)

Comment: this two cases are same, but when you enclose 0 in parenthesis, this operator look a like simple function, so it can be more accustomed for some developer

Comment: Exactly, this question _is not answerable_ void is an **operator**. The history behind the use of parenthesis on operators isn't really a valid query for this website.

Comment: It's a style thing, and beyond that it's a style for something that is only very rarely necessary.

Comment: actually, this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656453/many-people-write-javascriptvoid0-instead-of-javascriptvoid-0-in-hrefs

Comment: As you are right, parens make not much sense for `void 0` however, there are cases, even though they are rare, when parens do make sense. E.g. `if(typeof(a || b) === "string")` when `a` is undefined and `b` is set or for readability.

Comment: RE "style": I thought maybe there was a smidgen of a chance some legacy browser required the parentheses... or something. Sorry for the duplicate, didn't see anything when I first searched this.

Answer (score 2):

You're 100% right. The `void` **is** an operator rather than a function, one doesn't gain anything by using the parenthesis. It is simply like he would write `void (0)` (because `0 === (0)`)